# How to Change the BackGround color for datecontrol?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use the following style for change the datepicker colors in jquery.how to change the Date background color.Here It will show the blue color behind the 1,2,3, upto 30.I need to change that blue color?How to do this?

```
 <style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker {
   background: #333;
   border: 1px solid #555;
   color: #EEE;
 }
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add color in ".ui-datepicker td" class

for example

```
.ui-datepicker td {
border: 0;
padding: 1px;
background: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Its not change color..It will change only back Ground not in the 1,2,3, uptp 30 background

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.ui-state-default {
    background-color: #ccc !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uGEzp/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style type="text/css">
     .ui-datepicker {
      background: #999;
      border: 1px solid #555;
       color: #EEE;
       }
     </style>
```